# DAE file not loading multi texturing in threejs

Tags: three.js, textures, collada

i'm currently studying the threejs libray ( a webgl library , available here threejs.org ) .

I m able to load different king of mesh and animate them , but i m facing a problem which i can t determine origin :

i have a animated ( biped ) mesh with a material containing several texture for diffuse, specular and bumpmapping but when i load the mesh into my webgl script , only one texture is loaded ( the specular one ) , so my mesh is almost black and gray :(

i can t determine if it s a problem from the exported file ( 3dsmax to collada with openCollada exporter ) of if it's from my code

EDIT / Problem solved : Colladaloader needed a fix for multitextures support. Works perfectly on V65-dev. Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed an issue with the collada loader.

Fixed loader exists at https://github.com/gero3/three.js/blob/patch-10/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js

pull request is pending:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/4242